# Probability of solving at least $n-1$ out of $n$ questions correct twice vs. solving at least $2n-2$ out of $2n$ questions correct once

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> Candidate who correctly solves on an average $n-1$ questions out of $n$ goes in for an examination in two parts. In each part $n$ questions are proposed and he is required to solve $n-1$ of them. Show that if the two parts were merged in one and he were required to solve $2(n-1)$ questions out of the $2n$, his chances of passing would be improved in the ratio of $4$ to $5$ very nearly. (Accurately as $4n^2 - 4n + 1$ to $5n^2 - 5n + 1$.)

Here's what I did. The nonmerged probability is$$\left(\binom{n}{1}\left({{n-1}\over{n}}\right)^{n-1}\left({1\over{n}}\right) + \binom{n}{0}\left({{n-1}\over{n}}\right)^{n}\right)^2 = {{\left(n(n-1)^{n-1} + (n-1)^n  \right)^2}\over{n^{2n}}}= {{n^2(n-1)^{2n-2} + 2n(n-1)^{2n-1} + (n-1)^{2n}}\over{n^{2n}}}.$$The merged probability is$$\binom{2n}{2}\left({{n-1}\over{n}}\right)^{2n - 2}\left({1\over{n}}\right)^2 + \binom{2n}{1}\left({{n-1}\over{n}}\right)^{2n - 1}\left({1\over{n}}\right) + \binom{2n}{0}\left({{n-1}\over{n}}\right)^{2n} = {{n(2n-1)(n-1)^{2n-2} + 2n(n-1)^{2n-1} + (n-1)^{2n}}\over{n^{2n}}}.$$So we want to show that the expression$${{n(2n-1)(n-1)^{2n-2} + 2n(n-1)^{2n-1} + (n-1)^{2n}}\over{{n^2(n-1)^{2n-2} + 2n(n-1)^{2n-1} + (n-1)^{2n}}}}$$ equals$${{5n^2 - 5n + 1}\over{4n^2 - 4n + 1}},$$which I'm not sure how to go about proving. I've tried but the resulting expressions were just too ugly for me to simplify. Is there a neat trick/method I'm unfamiliar with? Or did I make algebra mistakes along the way? Any help would be well-appreciated.

Comment: Cancel common factors from the numerator and denominator. Seems like $(n-1)$ shows up a bunch...

Comment: Thanks as always @MikeEarnest. Silly oversight on my part, now I got it.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  This is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote (n-1)^(2n-2) as x, rest should be trivial. Factor out X, which appears in every monomial, and multiply out.